# Where clause when one item = this another item can = this or that : Case statement?

Tags: sql

I have this query below that i am trying to adjust the where clause to do when edittype = 601 or 603 paydesnum can not be (33,34,35) but when edit type does = 602 paydesnum can = any number.

I've tried doing a but a different case type statement but no luck. Would anyone be able to help?

Example Case statement:

```
   and Case 
          When s.edittype = 601 then s.paydesnum Not IN (33,34,35) 
          When s.edittype = 603 then s.paydesnum Not IN (33,34,35) 
          Else When s.edittype = 602 then s.paydesnum = any # 
end
```

Full Code:

```
Select s.FILEKEY,
case s.EDITTYPE
    when 601 then 'Incident Adjustment'
    when 602 then 'Incident Marker'
    when 603 then 'New Incident'
    else 'N/A'
end,
s.EFFDATE,
s.EFFTIME,
s.USERNAME,
s.PAYDESNUM as 'Incident #',
s.PREVPAYDES as 'Previous Incident #',
s.RATE as 'Points'


from SUPEDITHIST s

where 

filekey = (select FILEKEY from employees where IDNUM = 'AGU7843') --ENTER EMPLOYEE ID 

and s.edittype in (601,602,603)
and s.paydesnum Not IN (33,34,35)       

--Change Dates if needed.
and s.effdate between '1/1/2015' and '12/31/2030'

order by 3
```

Comment: I think your question may be misworded as it currently states an edittype of 601 or 602 cannot have a paydesnum of 33 through 35, but an edittype of 602 can. Should one of those instances of 602 be something else?

Comment: Part of your difficulty is that you want to use `case` as something to steer the execution of the query by making the filters dynamic. It's actually just an expression that has an output value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in this part of your question:

> but when edit type does = 602 paydesnum can = any number

there is a typo and it should be:

> but when edit type does = 603 paydesnum can = any number

So the solution is:

```
...and ((s.edittype in (601, 602) and s.paydesnum not in (33,34,35)) or s.edittype = 603)
```

Comment: Thank you, It was a type o, and this did solve my problem. I guess I was just way overthinking it and needed something more complicated to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
not (s.edittype in (601, 602, 603) and paydesnum IN (33, 34, 35)) and
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
(s.edittype not in (601, 602, 603) or paydesnum Not IN (33, 34, 35)) and
```

Note:  This logic may not do what you want for `NULL` values, but they can easily be adjusted.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but let me include something I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are close except for some confusion about edit type code.

```
(edittype in (601, 603) and paydesnum not in (33, 34, 35) or edittype = 602)
```